# Turning a Java application into a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, input, dataset

I have created a recommender system in Java that does the following:
 1. takes in a dataset that is in the form of a CSV file
 2. takes user input
 3. compares the user input with the data from the dataset
 4. calculates predictions
 5. provides recommendations to the user based on the calculations

However, I am now trying to change that same recommender system into the form of a Web application.

Is there a way to still use the code from my Java application or will I have to create a similar recommender system in a new language/format?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's exactly what you want but let's see:

You should be able to copy the logic if you followed the MVC pattern(if you kept UI and logic seperate).

In this case, you can create a new dynamic web project, add the model(logic) and build your own view/controller(UI) using servlets around it.

If you didn't follow the MVC pattern, it might get difficult to adopt everything but it should at least be possible to copy parts of it.

[**Note**]

MVC(Model View Controller) is a best practice.

It means that you have model classes that contain your logic, controller classes that are for communicating between the model and the view and the view that contain the UI(e.g. FXML or JSP files).

MVC makes it easier to have multiple UIs/switch between UIs as you want.

Comment: I'm very sorry.
 
I meant to say that I want to create that same recommender system in the form of a Web application that does all the same things that the Java application does.

I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry. You can just copy the logic of the recommander system but you will have to rewrite anything UI-related.